# How to add 2 toast in different ratings?

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to show 2 toast in different rating.When user click on submit Button,It show toast msg. If it is  5 star show Toast "msg1".
If less than 5 stars, change Toast "msg2".

Here is my code.

```
   dialogView.findViewById(R.id.review_rating).setOnTouchListener
            (new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        float touchPositionX = event.getX();
                        float width = review_rating.getWidth();
                        float starsf = (touchPositionX / width) * 5.0f;
                        int stars = (int) starsf + 1;
                        if (stars > 5) {
                            stars = 5;
                        }
                        rating_stars = stars + "";
                        review_rating.setRating(stars);

                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, stars + " rate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        v.setPressed(false);
                    }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        v.setPressed(true);
                    }
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                        v.setPressed(false);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {



                }
            }

    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use somthing like this..

```
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.review_rating).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    float touchPositionX = event.getX();
    float width = review_rating.getWidth();
    float starsf = (touchPositionX / width) * 5.0f;
    int stars = (int) starsf + 1;
    if (stars > 5) {
    stars = 5;
    }

    rating_stars = stars + "";
    review_rating.setRating(stars);
    if(stars>=5){
    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "MESSAGE 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(stars<5){
    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "MESSAGE 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    v.setPressed(false);
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    v.setPressed(true);
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
    v.setPressed(false);
    }
    return true;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use ratings bar( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) for your code. It will dynamically show messages to the user based on their ratings.

In your activity.xml add:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your activity.java, onCreate method add:

```
RatingBar r2 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating2);

r2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar r2, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            if(rating<=2)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(rating<=3.5)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unsatisfactory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Great", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

As soon as rating is changed, RatingBarChangeListener is called and you can also add messages based on your application

Hope it helps !!